# Polygons with WKT extension load extremely slow

Tags: qgis, csv, well-known-text, timemanager

I am quite new to QGIS. I have temporal data per month for the period of 8 years for all Indian districts (+/- 650 districts). This means I have approx. 65.000 objects in my attributes table. Once I upload my file as a layer (a text delimited file) in QGIS using WKT-text, the polyons load extremely slow.

Is there anything I can do about this? I would ultimately like to use the time-manager to visualize my temporal data on India.

Comment: Use something/anything else than WKT text: PostGIS, GeoPackage, GeoJSON, good old shape files.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Does that mean I can just export/save the layer as a geopackage? Does that already do the job. I am not familiar with Post-GIS.

Answer (score 2):

You can speed up CSVs by using the spatial index as stated at [QGIS user manual](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/opening_data.html#importing-a-delimited-text-file) within [this chapter](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/opening_data.html#layer-settings).

[image]

However, as already [stated in comments](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/375245/polygons-with-wkt-extension-load-extremely-slow/375246#comment613199_375245), using another file format or especially a spatial database like PostGIS can have more effect.